# Python: How does the tuple to list type casting work?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am curious to know how python internally handles the type casting of tuple to a list. For example,

```
>>> list((1,2,3))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Does it internally calls a for loop to add it to a list or its merely a type conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python doesn't have "type casting". The iterable is passed to the [`list` initializer](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Objects/listobject.c#l2438), which delegates it to the [`extend()` method](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Objects/listobject.c#l798).

Answer (score 1):

It iterates over the given object, much like in a for loop, thus supporting also iterators like files or generator functions.

[This](http://hbfs.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/python-iterators/) is a good explanation of python's iterable objects.